# nokogiri-1.7.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.0.0p648

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Getting this error when I run bundle install in a project

```
nokogiri-1.7.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.0.0p648
```

I use rbenv and

```
ruby -v          
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin16.0]
```

I'm on OSX latest

Comment: Is this inside a Rails or other type of project's Gemfile? The ruby version your rails application is depending on and that your machine is pointing to might be different.

Comment: @Schwad i cloned a project from github and ran `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, try putting `ruby '2.1.0'` atop your Gemfile.

Comment: Is there a .ruby-version file in your project? If so, replace contents with '2.1.0'

Comment: @mr_sudaca no https://scrnshot.s3.amazonaws.com/example-quickstart_2017-04-11_18-55-00.png

Comment: Try `rvm ls` to see the output if you actually do have rvm?

Comment: The issue must be from your system if it believes you are operating on Ruby 2.0.0?